# Image gets clipped while changing orientation using Qt

Tags: image, qt, viewer

HI all,

I wnt to develop an ImageViewer using qt. I m trying to resize big images by scaling them. My problem is , when i change the screen orientation some part of the image gets clipped and also if i open the image in landscape mode, by default the size of image remains small even when i change back to portrait mode. What am i Doin wrong?

Please help me out. Heres the code dat i hv written

ImageViewer::ImageViewer()
{
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
    QAction *back = new QAction(this);
    back->setText(QString("Back"));
    connect(back,SIGNAL(triggered()),this,SLOT(close()));
    back->setSoftKeyRole(QAction::PositiveSoftKey);
    addAction(back);

```
imageLabel = new QLabel();
imageLabel->setSizePolicy(QSizePolicy::Expanding,QSizePolicy::Expanding);
imageLabel->setAlignment(/*Qt::AlignLeft|*/Qt::AlignCenter);
QWidget *widget = new QWidget;
layout=new QStackedLayout();
layout->addWidget(imageLabel);
widget->setLayout(layout);
setCentralWidget(widget);
```

}

void ImageViewer::showImage(QString filePath)
 {
     QImageReader reader;
     reader.setFileName(filePath);
     QSize imageSize = reader.size();
     imageSize.scale(size(), Qt::KeepAspectRatio);
     reader.setScaledSize(imageSize);
     QImage image = reader.read();
     imageLabel->setPixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
     imageLabel->adjustSize();
  }

Answer (score 0):

You should re-implement QLabel's [resizeEvent](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#resizeEvent) or install event filter to it and handle QResizeEvent there
The content of showImage method should go to handler of a resize event.
Currently you are using size() of ImageViewer widget (which seems to be derived from QMainWindow), it's better to use imageLabel.size(); or the best QResizeEvent::size() as this will prevent a problem if you will change UI layout in future.

Comment: I am sorry I have to say i didnt understand it. Could you give an eaxmple for it?